# Express Router - the router loads partial paths?

Tags: express, react-router

I have only one route defined with the following path:

`:page?/:pagination?`

As you can see, `page` and `pagination` are optional.

In my browser, if i call the path `/test` for example, i still get the result of the first route.
How can i fix it?

Comment: What do you mean, "the result of the first route"?

Comment: When i call `/test` it's "calling" the `:page?/:pagination?` function when it should throw an error because i don't have the `/test` path defined in my routes.

Comment: But `/test` matches `/:page?`.

Answer (score 0):

An option here is to require the 'page' route. If a user navigates to that without the 'pagination' there should be a default view. If the user then, let's say, searches for something, then the paginated search results are shown.

For example, lets say we have some products. If the user navigates to /products then there is a products overview page with a search bar on it. If the user searches for a product, the view changes to a paginated list of products, e.g., /products/page1. The pagination buttons then navigate the user to other products. If the user directly accesses a URL such as /products/page3 then the API calls have to be made accordingly.

Another option is to not even have "pages" and instead have the component fetch and render more items upon button click.